# C# DataGrid SQL Query With Relation Column Name

Tags: c#, sql, relation

I have 2 tables with the following columns:

Table `Invoices`

| id | customer_id |
| --- | --- |

Table `Customers`

| id | customer_name |
| --- | --- |

`Invoices.Customer_id` and `Customers.id` are relationshiped.

Im trying to list Invoices with customer name (rather than id column) from Customers, but cannot succeed.

Im using windows forms

My Model Codes like;

```
public List<Invoice> InvoiceList()
    {
        List<Invoice> Invoices = new List<Invoice>();

        Invoices = connection.Query<Invoice>("SELECT Invoices.amount,Invoices.customer_id,Customers.customer_name as CustomerName FROM Invoices INNER JOIN Customers ON Customers.id=Invoices.customer_id").ToList();

       return Invoices;

    }
```

forms Codes are below;

```
void InvoiceList()
    {
        using (InvoiceRepository invoices= new InvoiceRepository ())
        {
                      

           datagridinvoice.DataSource = invoices.InvoiceList();
    
        }
    }
```

It shows like below;

[image]

Comment: please show the code that you use to run the query with all, i usually put the result in a a´datatable or dataset and use that as datasource

Comment: Is it WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET?.. What type has InvoiceList?

Comment: I have updated the codes  and added picture